# How can I automatically stamp a name or data associated with a phone number entry?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, autosuggest, dataprovider

I have a sheet where I keep track of who I called & who called me. On this sheet I need to make a automatic stamp so that I would be able to see who is calling.

I register phone numbers in column B and the names associated with the number in column C. This is all done manually.

How can I stamp the name in column C depending on the phone number entered in column B?

For example: When I write down 9955323155 in Column B /cell B150/ then the script would stamp "Zaka" in Column C /cell C150/ automatically.

[image]

Are there any simple script or add-on for this purposes?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This formula in C4

```
={"Name"; arrayformula(iferror(if(len(B5:B), vlookup(B5:B, 'Data for Name stamp'!A:B, 2, 0),)))}
```

will lookup any known phone numbers and return the names.
Note that names can not be entered manually in this column but have to be added to the helper sheet.
See if that works?